# stopping image loading with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I have a web-page, containing image miniatures. Click on miniature calls javascript, that appends to DOM full-image gallery, and opens it in a modal view. Browser starts immediate fetching images after an appending, but the problem is that they are still fetching after the modal gallery is closed and the gallery is deleted from DOM. Is there any way to stop image loading? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.stop()
```

it did the trick